# Background color of a view inside custom tableCell not displays well iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I receive a color from the server and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I'm trying to apply this color to a view inside the cell.

The problem is that all the cells display the same color until I scroll down the table. When I start scrolling they update well their color.

I'm new on iOS and Objective-C, so if you could help me it would be appreciated, thanks.

Before scrolling:

[image: Before scrolling]

After scrolling:

[image: After scrolling]

Some code: (If you want more please tell me)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   CalendarDayCell *cell = (CalendarDayCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CalendarDayCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CalendarDayCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CalendarDayCell"];
    }
    if (self.events.count) {
        CalendarEvent *ce = self.events[indexPath.row];
        CalendarDayCell *dayCell = (CalendarDayCell *) cell;
        // ...
        dayCell.viewColorBar.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:ce.color];
        return dayCell;
    } else {
        // Not important
    }    
}
```

PS: I've also tried it at `willDisplayCell` method with the same results.

**EDIT:**

Finally I figured out what were the solutions.

1. IDK why XCode redimensioned the color bar height to be 980px from the 50px that I specified in the nib file. And that was causing that all cells below had the same color.
2. I put all the views in another view, and assigned that view to the cell because some cells were not showing their color.

that's all

Comment: did you try going `[self.tableview reloadData]` when the colour is supposed to change?

Comment: Yes, but is displaying blank cells. Maybe I should mention i'm using a TableView inside ViewController and not a TableViewController. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with reusing the cells - that means that in cellForRowAtIndex path you have to set color for every condition. This is easily reproducible with images. If you set image only sometimes, you will have to set image to none when you don't need to display it. What you need to do is to handle in the else block the control you want to change.

```
if(self.events.count){
    dayCell.viewColorBar.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:ce.color];
}
else{
    dayCell.viewColorBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Self.events is populated with correct data so it didn't work. Thx.

Comment: Is there any place where you set your color to blue?

Comment: No, I receive an array of events from server, each event has a color and it is what i'm trying to assign to the cell view. In case that color weren't correct the view turns yellow.

Comment: can you change dayCell.viewColorBar.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:ce.color];
         to [UIColor redColor] and see if the problem persists?

Comment: it could be problem with data source(events) or method itself. Also if you could post example string of ce.color

Comment: If I assign a fixed color it works, the problem is when each cell have different colors. The color parser works well, but an example of an event color is: f2c821 or 3d21f2

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `self.events.count` is actually non-zero? Perhaps the tableview is being populated before `self.events` is setup properly.

For example, the view controller might be loading via `viewDidLoad`, then the UITableView, then you're setting `self.events`.  If that's the case, `self.events` will be `nil` until the whole view/viewcontroller is loaded.  That would account for it working *after* you start scrolling.

Comment: Yes, self.events isn't null. I've checked the load order and should be ok. Thx.

Comment: Is the default color of viewColorBar.backgroundColor the red-orange color in the top screenshot?  What happens if you simply set cell.viewColorBar.bar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor] and return it straight away--before `if (self.events.count)`?

Comment: Nope. The default color is yellow, setted in the storyboard. If I set a color outside if (self.events.count) it shows that color well. is kinda weird.